# Android Rest API listening for database changes

Tags: php, android, laravel, rest, api

I have a Laravel backend (Rest API) and I have made an Android application for that using the Volley library.
My question is how to listen for database changes in the backend from the Android application. I want to have listeners like firebase.

Comment: You can open a socket from your app and listen to changes in your database through that socket.
Refer this link to know abut Socket.io - https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java
 @Habib Mhamadi

Comment: How to use it with volley and what do i need to use in laravel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to open a streamed connection from the app to the server, but this requires the server to implement WebSocket programming.